# Auto update cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, database

Is there some formula which can be used for cell linking. means if I type something in cell A1 and want some wanted result in B1.
For example
I type "A" in Cell A1 and it shows "Apple" in Cell B1
I type "C" in cell A2 and it shows in "Italy" in cell B2

Thanks

Comment: *For example I type "A" in Cell A1 and it shows "Apple" in Cell B1 I type "C" in cell A2 and it shows in "Italy" in cell B2* You need 2 separate formulas - in B1 and in B2. Like `B1=IF(A1="A","Apple","")` and `B2=IF(A2="C","Italy","")`. If you have more complex dependencies you may create dependency tables in some ranges (maybe on service worksheet) and use VLOOKUP() function.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new workbook, we will call it **workbook 2**
2. The first column is your index and the second column the result.
   [image: Info added in Workbook 2]
3. In **workbook 1** you will have two cells, a input an a output. Input is a blank cell where you write your index. The output cell will need to have a formula, in this case, a **=VLOOKUP** formula. **=VLOOKUP(B3;workbook2!A1:B4;2;0)**
   [image]
4. The VLOOKUP has 4 main parameters. =VLOOKUP(value to lookup;where to lookup;column related to the search;approximate or exact value (true[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voZnk.png) or false [0]))

If later on you need to add more values, just update your table on **workbook 2**
and it will be recognized on your formula on **workbook 1**